# Workaround for mounting a filesystem to a local directory without elevated privileges on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, permissions

I've got an ext3 filesystem sitting in a file, and I'd like to mount it to a local directory without sudo or any elevated permissions. Why? I'm creating a small filesystem for automated testing purposes. The automated tests run on machines I do not control, so there are some barriers to adding mount to sudoers.

Here's how I created the filesystem:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./50MB_partition count=102400
$ mkfs.ext3 -F 50MB_partition
```

Had I had permission, I could now mount it like so:

```
$ mkdir small_partition
$ sudo mount 50MB_partition ./small_partition
```

It seems that, because I own the filesystem and the mount point, there is no security risk associated with allowing me to mount this. I understand what is limiting me from calling mount without sudo; no explanation needed there. What I want to know is, is there a workaround that allows me to use my filesystem for testing purposes?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/how-to-mount-an-image-file-without-root-permission

Answer (score 3):

mount requires mount() [defined in sys/mount.h] which, in turn, requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN, so you can't use mount() without a fstab entry or sudo.

might want to look into fuse (filesystem in userspace) [ http://fuse.sourceforge.net/ ]

Comment: Fuse is a good direction to look.  In particular see http://fuse-ext2.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Might you suggest mounting with pvfs2fuse or some such?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to mount to do this, `owner`, which also implies other options to prevent security violations.

> `owner`
>
> Allow an ordinary (i.e., non-root) user to mount the filesystem if he
>   is the owner of the device. This option implies the options `nosuid` and
>   `nodev` (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line
>   `owner,dev,suid`).

The problem is that it requires the "device" to be owned by you. There is no device in this case. The device (/dev/loopx) is automatically setup by mount, which requires root privileges, and then the device isn't owned by you.

Not sure how to work around that, unless, you can get a root user to use losetup and then chown the loop device to you.

It's also possible that this needs to be mentioned in `/etc/fstab` for the `owner` option to be accepted. Not sure since it isn't documented in the man page I have and I haven't tried it.

Comment: I tried to find a workaround for the losetup root user requirement. Doesn't look like there's something out there for that. Looks like the /etc/fstab mention isn't needed, though.